# spyder, distribute & scipy error

Tags: installation, scipy, pip, spyder

I am running python 2.7 under ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to install spyder using pip but get the error message:

### error: invalid command 'egg_info'

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1

I looked at other posts, which recommended I install distribute.  But I get the same error message when installing distribute using pip
When I try to upgrade scipy or install spyder with pip I get the following message:

```
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 980, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 216, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 255, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode))
InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
```

I'm new to python, pip and ubuntu, which makes this more difficult.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can install spyder by simply typing following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install spyder
```

The another way is :

Open "Ubuntu Software Center" search for spyder and click on "Install."

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) Maybe your problem is because Ubuntu 12.04 has an outdated version of `pip`. You can update it using `sudo easy_install pip`, and then try again.

You can also try to use `easy_install` instead of `pip` to install Spyder. Just run the command `sudo easy_install spyder` to see if that works.

*Notes*:

1. If these solutions don't work for you but you still want to try the latest Spyder (and other scientific packages like `scipy` or `pandas`), you'll have a much better time by installing a Python scientific distribution like [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).
2. Don't try to install `scipy` with `pip`. That's not so easy as installing Spyder.